# geospatial search error mongodb

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I am trying to access a document in collection based on the 2dgeosphare but it is not working, Please find the screenshot of the [document and search error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4HP9.jpg)document and errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created an index?

db.kudu.createIndex({loc:"2dsphere"})

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was doing it wrong. as mentioned in the screenshot. db.kudu.createIndex({point:"2dsphere"})